# Как передать аргументы self-функции python?

Tags: python

Функция `def func(self, event):` вызывается в коде строкой `keyboard.hook(self.func)`

Помимо `self` и `event`, в функцию нужно предать еще один аргумент в виде числа.

**То есть что-то такое:**

```
#функция

def func(self, event, my_varible):
     if my_varible == 1:
          #действие 1
     else:
          #действие 2

#вызов

keyboard.hook(self.func(1)) #как передать значение?
```

**Как это можно сделать?**

Comment: Укажите явно `keyboard.hook(self.func(my_varible=1))`

Comment: Теперь выводит ошибку, о том что упущен аргумент `event`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
keyboard.hook(self.func(1))
                       ^^^ - вызов функции, вместо передачи её аргументом
```

Если вы указываете скобки с аргументом, вы вызываете функцию в этот самый момент уже, а не передаёте ссылку на функцию, что требуется в этом случае, так точно не пойдёт. Но можно использовать, например, `partial`. Примерно так:

```
from functools import partial

keyboard.hook(partial(self.func, my_variable=1))
```